# Find in Eclipse overwrites Linux clipboard

Tags: eclipse, clipboard

I have this little annoyance with Eclipse under Linux.
Let's say I select some text in a terminal window, maybe an error message. Then I go to Eclipse and open Find/Replace (Ctrl+F) to search for the error in my code. But then, some text in the Find box is auto-selected, which overwrites what I had in the middle-click buffer. So I have to clear the Find box, go back to the terminal and re-select, then back to Eclipse and paste in the search box.

Is there any trick around this? Can I make Find open with an empty search box? Or should I just learn to use Ctrl+Shift+C and Ctrl+V to copy from a terminal to Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a known issue...
not sure it's gonna be fixed
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=415939